# mlock usage in RAM only system

Tags: embedded-linux

We have a time-critical process (third party code) and it has mlockall. I am porting this code to our embedded system which doesnt have a hard disk.
It is RAM only system, which boots from SD card and has storage as well in SD card.

Does mlockall has any performance benefits at all in an RAM only system?

Just to check whether there is any swap partition it tried:
cat /proc/swaps
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority

In this case can i remove mlockall as it is not going to add any value in our system. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

When under memory pressure the linux kernel might decide to evict pages from RAM. Dirty pages (containing writeable data) can only be swapped out. Clean pages (read only) like the text section of your process might just be dropped. Such pages would be brought back in via a page fault when needed.

The first case can not happen to you as there is no swap. The second case might happen and could be prevented via the mlockall call.

Overall the discussion is theoretical as running a system under memory pressure introduces a lot of non deterministic behaviour which is bad for a real time system.